# Libevent + Comet (Long-Polling / Http-Stream)

Tags: comet, libevent

Hey folks! Im looking for a good tutorial on how to implement a long polling or http stream server based on libevent.
The few examples which google showed up are either with errors or not exactly what i am looking for. Perhaps anyone of you guys has already experience with libevent and longpolling/http-Stream/Comet and could help with some examples?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres an example: http://code.google.com/p/libevent-longpolling/source/browse/

Comment: It does not work... seams that its due to my x86 cpu?

libevent-lp$ make
cc -o libevent-longpolling main.o -levent
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `main.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Fehler 1

Comment: Just do a gmake/make clean and then gmake/make. The Makefile should take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another example: https://github.com/ideawu/icomet, a long-polling comet server built with libevent 2.